# Asymptotic analysis of non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, asymptotics, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for references on the topic of asymptotic analysis of non linear ODE's of the sort
$$
x'' + x'x = 0
$$
This specific case has an analytic solution (with some $\tanh(\cdots)$ involved) and quickly converges to a real value; in my case, I'm dealing with "similar" equations, with some form of $x'x$ involved.

Comment: There are at least two ways. Like the example that you've attached to the post, your system of interest might have a first integral, which can be used to reduce it to the first order equation. Another way is to transform this 2nd order ODE to system of 1st order ODEs and study its attractors.

Comment: Could you recommend any reference?

Comment: If you are interested in good or/and comprehensive texts regarding analysis of systems of ODEs, consider books by Hirsch+Smale, Wiggins and Meiss. However there are many texts that cover basics of what you might need if you follow the 2nd way of asymptotic analysis.